# How to specify the validated field in jQuery-validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 fields: Name Query and Date of Birth, while Name Query is mandatory and DoB isn't. I have the following form to show an validation message under the Name Query field:

```js
var myForm = $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required",
    DoBQuery: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query field",
    DoBQuery: ""
  }
});
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="NameQuery">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="DoBQuery">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="DoBQuery" name="DoBQuery">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Now I'd like to add some styling to the Name Query field validation message. Some code was added to the snippet, notice that the `<div class="error__input"></div>` has to **EXIST IN BOTH FIELDS** like in the snippet

```js
var myForm = $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required",
    DoBQuery: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query field",
    DoBQuery: ""
  },
  errorElement : 'div',
  errorLabelContainer: '.error__input'
});
```

```css
.error__input{
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="NameQuery">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
    <div class="error__input"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="DoBQuery">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="DoBQuery" name="DoBQuery">
    <div class="error__input"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Now the validation message exists in both fields, I understand that jQuery-validate finds the `error__input` div and apply the class to it, but why does it add the message to the second field and how can I set the alert message to apply only on the first message while both `<div class="error__input"></div>` have to be there?

Comment: That's because you didn't read the documentation for how to properly use the `errorLabelContainer` option.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this, I guess:

```js
var myForm = $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required",
    DoBQuery: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query field",
    DoBQuery: ""
  }
});
```

```css
#myform .error {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}

#myform input {
  display: inline;
}

#myform > div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="NameQuery">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery" style="display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="DoBQuery">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="DoBQuery" name="DoBQuery" style="display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But I think the `input` class is no longer needed.

Comment: @thinkvantagedu What about your "notice that the `<div class="error__input"></div>` has to **EXIST IN BOTH FIELDS**"? Where is those fields in this solution?

Comment: @ReSedano I probably did not make myself clear enough, what I meant was solely removing `<div class="error__input"></div>` under DoB field was not allowed, but removing both was okay. Your solution was a good one too.

Comment: @thinkvantagedu Well, this is the normal use of that validate plugin. Nothing special here. But, well the important thing is that you have solved your problem. Cheers. :-)

Comment: @ReSedano Learned something from your answer as well, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [errorPlacement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to put your error message next to the error element.

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element){
   error.appendTo(element.next(".error__input"));
}
```

```js
var myForm = $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required",
    DoBQuery: {
      required: false /* if it is not required, why you put here? You can simply not insert this input field in validate()'s rules. */
    }
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query field"
  },
  errorElement : 'div',
  errorPlacement: function(error,element){
    error.appendTo(element.next(".error__input"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="NameQuery">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
    <div class="error__input"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="DoBQuery">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="DoBQuery" name="DoBQuery">
    <div class="error__input"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should remove `<div class="error__input"></div>` tag after Date of Birth field

Comment: Sorry I mentioned that they cannot be removed.